# Get JSON generated by a webhook hosted online

Tags: php, json, webhooks

I am making a card payment and then it communicates to the server of the company via webhook, the response is then recorded in RequestBin, which generates a JSON response in their website, how do I extract the information from the website to my PHP code?

The webpage looks like this:
[my requestb.in online webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjAf.jpg)

What I need is to get that raw JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, first you download HTML dom and then you just change the fields. The reason the for loop goes from 0-19 is because requestb.in saves 20 entries, for the rest just substitute the variables.

```
    include('../simple_html_dom.php');

    // get DOM from URL or file
    // asegurese de incluir el ?inspect en el URL
    $html = file_get_html('https://requestb.in/YOURURL?inspect');

    for ($x = 0; $x <= 19; $x++) {
        $result = $html->find('pre[class=body prettyprint]', $x)->plaintext;
        if($result){
            $json_a = str_replace('&#34;', '"', $result);   
            $object = json_decode($json_a);
            if(isset($object->type)) echo $object->type . "<br>";
            if(isset($object->transaction->customer_id)) echo $object->transaction->customer_id . "<br>";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using CURL to retrieve the JSON object. Are you using CURL to send the payment payload out to the processor, etc? Below is an example (Obviously you would need to fill in the appropriate PHP variables where applicable).

```
$reqbody = json_encode($_REQUEST);
$serviceURL = "http://www.url.com/payment_processor";

$curl = curl_init($serviceURL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $reqbody);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);    

$headers = array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
    "Authorization: ".$hmac_enc,
    "apikey: ".$apikey,
    "token: ".$token,
    "timestamp: ".$timestamp,
    "nonce: ".$nonce,
);    

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 201 ) {
    die("Error: call to URL $serviceURL failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}

curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);

echo "<hr/><br/><strong>PROCESSOR RESPONSE:</strong><br/>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the json from requestbin and resend it to your localhost using a request client like Postman.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $data = json_decode($_POST);
}
```

Comment: Where or how do I specify the URL and what parameters do I need for the $_POST, I really am in zeroes, I have no idea how to approach this.